# PHP Send SSL to other web service API with .pem and key

Tags: php, json

I need to send the JsonData to other ABC system API via cert and key, but I always receive the error message:Curl error: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

when I check from the ABC System, there are no any data received, May I know what are possibilities will return this error?

Did anyone can help me check for my code, my certificate and password confirm is the correct one

```
function sendJsonDataToSSL_API2($https_url, $jsonData) {
    //base_url() . 
    $crtFile = 'http://www.example.com/certificate.crt';
    $pemfile = 'http://www.example.com/certificate.pem';
    $keyfile = 'http://www.example.com/privatekey.key';
    $cert_password = 'abcd1234';
    $url = $https_url;


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pemfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $cert_password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $crtFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $cert_password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonData))
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($output === false) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        //echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }


    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Instead of accessing certificates using URL's you should use file path.

Comment: Finally, there are something difference error message : Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api1.example.com:443
Thanks a lot :-)